# How to make an api call faster in Golang?

Tags: api, go, concurrency, goroutine

I am trying to upload bunch of files using the company's api to the storage service they provide. (basically to my account). I have got lots of files like 40-50 or something.
I got the full path of the files and utilize the `os.Open`, so that, I can pass the io.Reader. I did try to use `client.Files.Upload()` without `goroutines` but it took so much time to upload them and decided to use `goroutines`. Here the implementation that I tried. When I run the program it just uploads one file which is the one that has the lowest size or something that it waits for a long time. What is wrong with it? Is it not like every time for loops run it creates a `goroutine` continue its cycle and creates for every `file`? How to make it as fast as possible with `goroutines`?

```
var filePaths []string
var wg sync.WaitGroup

// fills the string of slice with fullpath of files.
func fill() {
    filepath.Walk(rootpath, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !info.IsDir() {
            filePaths = append(filePaths, path)
        }
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERROR:", err)
        }
        return nil
    })
}

func main() {
    fill()

    tokenSource := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(&oauth2.Token{AccessToken: token})
    oauthClient := oauth2.NewClient(context.TODO(), tokenSource)
    client := putio.NewClient(oauthClient)

    for _, path := range filePaths {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            f, err := os.Open(path)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("err:OPEN", err)
            }

            upload, err := client.Files.Upload(context.TODO(), f, path, 0)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("error uploading file:", err)
            }
            fmt.Println(upload)
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Inside the loop do `path := path` (to copy the string) somewhere above `go func() { ...`. Or you can do `go func(path string) { ... }(path)`. And see this [FAQ](https://go.dev/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines) for explanation.

Comment: ... and by the way your error "handling" is lacking.

Comment: If network or storage bandwidth is the limiting factor, concurrently uploading all files is not going to get you more bandwidth (though multiple streams may help up to a certain point, but you should determine what that is and limit the concurrency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a worker pool pattern like this: https://go.dev/play/p/p6SErj3L6Yc

In this example application, I've taken out the API call and just list the file names.  That makes it work on the playground.

- A fixed number of worker goroutines  are started.  We'll use a channel to distribute their work and we'll close the channel to communicate the end of the work.  This number could be 1 or 1000 routines, or more.  The number should be chosen based on how many concurrent API operations your putio API can reasonably be expected to support.
- `paths` is a `chan string` we'll use for this purpose.
- workers `range` over `paths` channel to receive new file paths to upload

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    paths := make(chan string)
    var wg = new(sync.WaitGroup)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(paths, wg)
    }
    if err := filepath.Walk("/usr", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("Failed to walk directory: %T %w", err, err)
        }
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        paths <- path
        return nil
    }); err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("failed Walk: %w", err))
    }
    close(paths)
    wg.Wait()
}

func worker(paths <-chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for path := range paths {
        // do upload.
        fmt.Println(path)
    }
}
```

This pattern can handle an indefinitely large amount of files without having to load the entire list in memory *before* processing it.  As you can see, this doesn't make the code more complicated - actually, it's simpler.

> When I run the program it just uploads one file which is the one

Function literals inherit the scope in which they were defined.  This is why our code only listed one path - the `path` variable scope in the for loop was shared to each go routine, so when that variable changed, all routines picked up the change.

Avoid function literals unless you actually *want* to inherit scope.  Functions defined at the global scope don't inherit any scope, and you must pass all relevant variables to those functions instead.  This is a good thing - it makes the functions more straightforward to understand and makes variable "ownership" transitions more explicit.

An appropriate case to use a function literal could be for the `os.Walk` parameter; its arguments are defined by `os.Walk` so definition scope is one way to access other values - such as `paths` channel, in our case.

Speaking of scope, global variables should be avoided unless their scope of usage is truly global.  Prefer passing variables between functions to sharing global variables.  Again, this makes variable ownership explicit and makes it easy to understand  which functions do and don't access which variables.  Neither your wait group nor your `filePaths` have any cause to be global.

```
            f, err := os.Open(path)
```

Don't forget to close any files you open.  When you're dealing with 40 or 50 files, letting all those open file handles pile up until the program ends isn't so bad, but it's a time bomb in your program that will go off when the number of files exceeds the `ulimit` of allowed open files.  Because the function execution greatly exceeds the part where the file needs to be open, `defer` doesn't make sense in this case.   I would use an explicit `f.Close()` after uploading the file.

Comment: thanks. let's say the API is expected to support 100 concurrent operations, If I change the number of worker goroutines to 100, would that make the whole process faster? considering we have 50 files to upload?  Or should I change the number of worker goroutines to the number of files to upload? 50 workers 50 files?

Comment: Set the number of workers to the number of concurrent operations - workers will function properly even if they receive 0 messages on the channel.

Comment: Do you mean the number of concurrent operations supported by the API? What if I don't know the exact number?

Comment: In a word, yes.  A limit on simultaneous or per-second operations on the API might be the practical limit on concurrency.  It's possible there could be some other limit - it depends on API behavior, bandwidth, file size.

Comment: Will it be faster?  If the files are much larger than your internet bandwidth, then the performance bottleneck is your internet connection, even one file is enough to saturate it, and running multiple uploads concurrently will not help much.  The smaller the files compared to bandwidth, the more latency effects performance, and the more opportunity for concurrency to improve performance.  For very small files, 100 simultaneous uploads could be about as fast as 1  upload of the largest file.