# error "data1.Body undefined (type []byte has no field or method Body)" when trying to decode a json's body

Tags: arrays, json, go, fasthttp

So again im trying to get this data but it is returning an error of

```
data.Body undefined (type []byte has no field or method Body)
```

on line 16 and 23 of this code. so when its decoding the json
If anyone could help me,
here is my code

```
func SkyblockActiveAuctions() (structs.SkyblockActiveAuctions, error) {
    var auctions structs.SkyblockActiveAuctions
    startTime := time.Now()
    statusCode, data, err := fasthttp.Get(nil, "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions")
    if err != nil {
        return auctions, err
    }
    fmt.Println(statusCode)
    var totalPages = auctions.TotalAuctions
    for i := 0; i < totalPages; i++ {
        statusCode, data1, err := fasthttp.Get(nil, "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions")
        if err != nil {
            return auctions, err
        }
        fmt.Println(statusCode)
        json.NewDecoder(data1.Body).Decode(&auctions)
        fmt.Println(auctions.LastUpdated)
    }
    endTime := time.Now()
    var timeTook = endTime.Sub(startTime).Milliseconds()
    fmt.Println(data)

    json.NewDecoder(data.Body).Decode(&auctions)

    fmt.Println(auctions.LastUpdated)
    fmt.Println(timeTook)

    return auctions, err
}
```

Comment: You're going to find far fewer surprises and a lot more example material using the std library http package, especially since you are still not familiar with the language. There's no reason to use the `fasthttp` package unless you have a problem it is specifically designed to solve.

Comment: Ok so im trying to get about 45 pages of 1000 items in a json what should i use if i want speed?

Comment: What is the bottleneck you are facing with `net/http`? "45 pages" is meaningless, and 45 requests at a time is hardly anything to be concerned with. If you have bottlenecks around allocation and garbage collection (outside of the json decoding, because that is an entirely different package), maybe look into `fasthttp`, but since you don't even yet have functioning code, I would wager you have not benchmarked this.

Comment: Thanks for this but is there any way to queue fasthttp Get requests asynchronously with my code?

Comment: The same way you do anything concurrently in Go, with goroutines.

Comment: @Ultimate, even the fasthttp documentation itself says you should stick with net/http. you may find this question useful for figuring out how to queue, or rather fan out,  your http requests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70217232/how-to-make-an-api-call-faster-in-golang/70218911#70218911

Comment: Here, if you go on to https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions and look at that, its like getting data similar to that 45 times, and if you want to check out the other pages, you just add ?page= and then 1 < totalPages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    json.NewDecoder(data.Body).Decode(&auctions)
```

> ```
> data.Body undefined (type []byte has no field or method Body)
> ```

[`data` is already the body of the response](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/valyala/fasthttp#Get).

[`json.NewDecoder` expects an `io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#NewDecoder) but since `fasthttp` has already read the data into `[]byte`, it would be more appropriate to use [`json.Unmarshal`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal):

```
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &auctions)
    if err != nil {
         return nil, err
    }
```

Don't forget to handle errors from `json.Unmarshal` (or, from `json.Decoder.Decode` for that matter).  `acutions` won't hold the expected data if the Json failed to parse, so you should handle that possiblity.